# Write regular expression to find all String that starts with one substring, except 2 cases

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

I need regular expresion (in VisualStudio 2013) to search all strings that start with `ab`, but do not start with `abc` or `abd`.

I tried `ab[^c][^d]*` but it didn't work.

Comment: My attempt : " ab[^c][^d]* " . Apparently not working. I am currently learning regular expressions, so I need some time and help.

Comment: ^ Great! Please edit that into your post, so that new readers of it do not have to wade through comments to understand its current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-All strings that start with 'ab'
2-but do not start with 'abc' or 'abd'.

Means: First 2 letters are 'ab', and third letter is not 'c' or 'd'

```
ab[^cd].*
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
^ab[^cd].*
```

This should do the trick.